# Using DNS to forward to a specific local address and port?

Tags: routing, ipv4, subnet, internet, dns

Im running a server on a local address, a raspberry pi at x.x.x.111:64738. 
I own a domain, mydomain.nu. I want to create a subdomain (the hosting provides a cPanel interface) and forward it to my public IP (i guess) and then in some way let my router handle the split to the raspberry's ip and server port. So when people use the DN "service.mydomain.nu" they'll get redirected to my Pi at port 64738, running the service.

The question is, how do I go about doing this? I guess it involves cname change or something like that but that's about how much I know..

Answer (score 0):

DNS only resolves names to IP addresses.  Create the DNS record pointing to your public IP.  Then you'll have to use your router to route port 64738 to the raspberry pi.

Comment: If you're not running an externally accessible webserver on port 80 in your home LAN and you want just the domain (default port 80) to get you to your RaspberryPi on the port you specified then you could do what Jim G says but forward port 80 to your specified IP and port. Port 80 will then be translated to the port you want your R.Pi is on.

Comment: Careful with this because the moment you set up a webserver anywhere else on your network, any requests will be sent to your RaspberryPi. Don't spend hours scratching your head because you've forgotten about a port forward.